# Determine the dimensions of the subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W_1$ denote the set of all polynomials $f(x)$ in $P(F)$ such that in the representation $f(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n−1}x^{n−1} + ··· + a_1x + a_0,$ we have $a_i = 0$ whenever $i$ is even. Likewise let $W_2$ denote the set of all polynomials $g(x)$ in $P(F)$ such that in the representation $g(x) = b_mx^m + b_{m−1}x^{m−1} + ··· + b_1x + b_0,$ we have $b_i = 0$ whenever $i$ is odd. Determine the dimensions of the subspaces  $W_1 ∩ P_n(F)$ and  $W_2 ∩ P_n(F).$

The set $W_1\cap P_n(F)$ consists of all the polynomials over the field $F$ that have degree of atmost $n$ and whose all even coefficients are zero. The basis for the set $W_1\cap P_n(F)$ is thus, $B=\{x,x^3,x^5,...,x^{n-1}\},$ if $n$ is even and if $n$ is odd then basis $B=\{x,x^3,x^5,...,x^n\}.$

So, $\dim (W)=|S|$ where, $S=\{1,3,5,...,n-1\}$ when $n$ is even and $S=\{1,3,5,...,n\}$ when $n$ is odd.

So, we have, $|S|=\frac n2$ when, $n$ is even and $|S|=\frac{n+1}{2},$ when $n$ is odd.

Finally, $\dim (W)=\frac n2$ when, $n$ is even and $\dim (W)=\frac{n+1}{2},$ when $n$ is odd.

The set $W_2\cap P_n(F)$ consists of all the polynomials over the field $F$ that have degree of atmost $n$ and whose all odd coefficients are zero. The basis for the set $W_1\cap P_n(F)$ is thus, $B=\{1,x^2,x^4,...,x^{n}\},$ if $n$ is even and if $n$ is odd then basis $B=\{1,x^2,x^4,...,x^{n-1}\}.$

So, $\dim (W)=|S|$ where, $S=\{0,2,4,...,n\}$ when $n$ is even and $S=\{0,2,4,...,n-1\}$ when $n$ is odd.

So, we have, $|S|=\frac n2 +1$ when, $n$ is even and $|S|=\frac{n-1}{2} +1,$ when $n$ is odd.

Finally, $\dim (W)=\frac n2 +1$ when, $n$ is even and $\dim (W)=\frac{n-1}{2} +1,$ when $n$ is odd.

---

However, the answer given in the book is : The dimension of $W_1∩P_n(F)$ and $W_2∩P_n(F)$ are $⌊\frac{n+1}2⌋$ and $⌈\frac{n+1}2⌉$ respectively.

I dont get where I made the mistake. Any help regarding this issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Those are the same as your answers.

Comment: @user114263 Thank you for confirming that my solution is valid!